# SQLite3 query fails

Tags: php, sqlite

SQLite3 query fails. Insert data in the database ok, but does not get the data, what is my fault?

```
protected function db2Array($data)
{
    $arr = array();
    while ($row = $data -> fetchArray(\SQLITE3_ASSOC))
    {
        $arr[] = $row;
    }
    return $arr;
}

function getNews()
{
    try
    {
        $sql = "SELECT msgs.id as id, 
                       title, 
                       category.name as category, 
                       description, 
                       source, 
                       datetime
                  FROM msgs,
                       category
                 WHERE category.id = msgs.category
              ORDER BY msgs.id DESC";
        $res = $this->_db -> query($sql);
        if(!is_object($res))
        {
            throw new Exception ($this->_db -> LastErrorMsg());
        }
        return $this->db2Array($res);
    }
    catch (Exception $exs)
    {
        //$exs -> getMessage();
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

This code return: array (size=0)empty

Comment: Does the query return an records when run directly?

Comment: Have you tried with a semicolon on the end?

Comment: yes, adds to the database correctly. did add a prepared query

Comment: sorry, i don't understand about semicolon. Where?

Comment: `adds` what? that is a select query not a insert query.

Comment: query return (var_dump()):  array (size=0)empty

Comment: @naut92 I meant add a semicolon to the end of the SQL string: `ORDER BY msgs.id DESC;`

Comment: @tuan as far as I know, the SQL request does not contain semicolon the end